# Should I (and how) run a php script with modal bootstrap?

Tags: php, modal-dialog

I have created a phpscript - calculator it's here
[How to optimize this short script in php - salary calc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35948084/how-to-optimize-this-short-script-in-php-salary-calc)
and it is working. 
Now I would like to do sth like this. A person on my web page clicks the button, the calculator opens in sth like little window, he uses calculator and when he finishes, closes the window with calculator and is on the webpage again. As I understand I should do it with bootstrap modal like this: http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/tryit.asp?filename=trybs_modal_sm&stacked=h
Do I understand it right?
How should I link my phpscript with this modal?

thank You for your hints?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what you need is an Ajax method with modal event listener,

Modal HTML

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open Small Modal</button>
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">
      <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
              <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <div id="showcal"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

B.S Modal event listener with Ajax Method

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: "calculator.php", //this file has the calculator function code
            success:function(data){
             $('#showcal').html(data);
            }
        });
     });
});
```

and in last `calculator.php`

```
<?php
       //Here comes the calculator code
?>
```

Lemme know if it worked and if not will make it work.

Comment: Hello and thx for your time and answer. So I am a very beginner and I need more clear explanation. What should I do? Modal HTML - this is what I copy to the page, right? What I do withe the B.S Modal... part and finally where do I copy the calculator.php? Thank You for Your help once more...

Comment: So to sum it up I have copied the modal html to my page but what to do with the BS Modal and where I should copy the calculator.php file? Thx again, H

Comment: lets say you have 2 files, 1 `index.php` which contains the modal HTML and ajax call script along with other necessary `css` and `js` lib for modal and ajax call to work, 2 file `calculator.php` which located at same path where `index.php` located and it contains the calculator function code

Comment: hmm unfortunatelly I am trying to do this in wordpress, so I think its other way, am I right? I understand what to do with html and calculator file but what about the wordpress who to create this ajax thing?

Comment: for ajax call look for plugin, i think there is one around, but i'm not sure the suggested answer will work out of the box in wordpress

Comment: Hiello, so I added html and BS Modal scripts to index, I have calculator file in the same path. When I enter the www I can see the button it opens the box but without calculator. So what's wrong?

Comment: SO I am going to try on the other way, I hope You can hint me. On my local server (127.0.0.1) I created a folder ajax_test in this folder index file - I copied there Modal HTML (from above) I also copied calculator.php (working script) And when I enter the 127.0.0.1/ajax_test the page with the button opens BUT what now should I do. Where to copy the B.S. Modal file? Please  help me :) Hubert

Comment: OK so now its working :) I did not write it between <script> </script>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106470/discussion-between-hubert-kubasiewicz-and-shehary).